# How do I tranpose a list in Elixir?

Tags: erlang, elixir

I wish efficiently to transpose a (large) list of lists in Elixir, where each sublist has the same number of scalar elements. So from this:

```
iex(1)> x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
```

I want to get to this:

```
[[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

In Python I would use the "splat" operator `*` with `zip`:

```
In [1]: x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
In [2]: x
Out[2]: [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
In [3]: zip(*x)
Out[3]: [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

This is exactly equivalent to tranposing a matrix.

What is the equivalent in Elixir? I need to do this for large lists of lists coming from CSVs.

Bonus: similar for maps eg:

```
iex(1)> %{"a1" => %{"d1" => 1, "d2" => 2}, "a2" => %{"d1" => 3, "d2" => 4}, "a3" => %{"d1" => 5, "d2" => 6}}
%{
  "a1" => %{"d1" => 1, "d2" => 2},
  "a2" => %{"d1" => 3, "d2" => 4},
  "a3" => %{"d1" => 5, "d2" => 6}
}
```

becomes

```
%{
  "d1" => %{"a1" => 1, "a2" => 3, "a3" => 5},
  "d2" => %{"a1" => 2, "a2" => 4, "a3" => 6}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lists you have [`Enum.zip/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Enum.html#zip/1) and [`Stream.zip/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#zip/1)

```rb
iex> Enum.zip([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
[{1, 3, 5}, {2, 4, 6}]
```

Rearranging the map gets a little more tricky. I'm sure there's a much cleverer, better way of doing it, but you could break it into a flat enumerable then form it back into a map. And here, I would look at using a comprehension.

```rb
iex> input = %{
...>   "a1" => %{"d1" => 1, "d2" => 2},
...>   "a2" => %{"d1" => 3, "d2" => 4},
...>   "a3" => %{"d1" => 5, "d2" => 6}
...> }
iex> for {outer, map} <- input, {inner, value} <- map, reduce: %{} do
...>   acc -> Map.update(acc, inner, %{outer => value}, &Map.put(&1, outer, value))
...> end
%{
  "d1" => %{"a1" => 1, "a2" => 3, "a3" => 5}, 
  "d2" => %{"a1" => 2, "a2" => 4, "a3" => 6}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For lists:

As BrettBeatty mentioned, you can use zip/1 as follows:

```
iex(1)> x = [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
iex(2)> x |> Enum.zip |>  Enum.map(&(Tuple.to_list(&1)))
```

There is also a recursive way to do it as well:

```
defmodule E do
  def transpose([]), do: []
  def transpose([[]|_]), do: []
  def transpose(list) do
    [Enum.map(list, &hd/1) | transpose(Enum.map(list, &tl/1))]
  end
end

iex(3)> x |> E.transpose()
```

Answer (score 1):

Brett’s answer is absolutely correct; I just wanted to share another approach for transposing maps using [`Kernel.put_in/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Kernel.html?#put_in/3) with [`Access.key/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/master/Access.html?#key/2). This approach is *easily* extendable to transpose maps of any depth.

```rb
Enum.reduce(map, %{}, fn {k, vs}, acc ->
  Enum.reduce(vs, acc, fn {ik, iv}, acc ->
    put_in(acc, [Access.key(ik, %{}), k], iv)
  end)
end)

#⇒ %{
#    "d1" => %{"a1" => 1, "a2" => 3, "a3" => 5},
#    "d2" => %{"a1" => 2, "a2" => 4, "a3" => 6}
#  }
```

`Access.key/2` accepts a default value, allowing you to bury an element as deep as needed.

```rb
put_in(%{}, [
  Access.key(:k1, %{}),
  Access.key(:k2, %{}),
  Access.key(:k3, %{})
], 42)
#⇒ %{k1: %{k2: %{k3: 42}}}
```

---

`Access`-based solution for transposing the array is also possible, but there is a need to know the length of the resulting list upfront.

```rb
len = list |> Enum.map(&Enum.count/1) |> Enum.max()
Enum.map(0..len-1, fn idx ->
  Enum.map(list, &get_in(&1, [Access.at(idx)]))
end)
#⇒ [[1, 3, 5], [2, 4, 6]]
```

Unlike `Enum.zip/1`, it’ll preserve all the elements, putting `nil`s where the input is shorter than max length.

Comment: Awesome for ragged arrays.

Comment: I personally prefer `Access` over all the native `Map`/`List`/`Enum` methods because it allows to easily generalize everything.

Comment: If you add the Enum.zip method to complete the question for lists, I will accept your excellent general answer as the main answer.

Comment: I do not like `Enum.zip/1` here because it produces tuples which are to be converted to lists afterward which is a) slow and b) simply fails when the length is greater than 255 (tuples max size is 255.) I might post the answer with `Enum.reduce/3` for lists but I like the approach above.

Comment: Oups; the comment above is wrong, tuples might be of [any reasonable size](https://bugs.erlang.org/browse/ERL-577). Anyway, I find converting to tuples and then from tuples redundant and not elegant.